# How can I prove commutative rings are stably finite?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I have a proof that shows that a *stably finite* ring (i.e. one where $AB=I\iff BA=I$ for any two square matrices $A,B$ with entries in the ring) has the Invariant Basis Number (IBN). Trouble is, it is used to prove that a commutative ring has IBN. So naturally the question is:

> How do I prove that a commutative ring is stably finite?

And could you give me an example of a stably finite non-commutative ring?

Comment: You don't need to prove stable finiteness in order to show that a commutative ring has IBN. Just factor by a maximal ideal and use the fact that fields have IBN.

Comment: Well I'm just trying to use what the teacher told us. And how do I prove a field has IBN anyway?

Comment: The proof that two bases of a vector space over a field have the same cardinality is very easy and basic.

Comment: OK I guess I can just take out my Linear Algebra notes for that. "factor by an ideal" means considering the quotient right? But if the ideal is prime, the quotient is a domain, not necessarily a field. And even if it is a field, how does that factorization prove my statement?

Comment: If $M$ is a free module over $R$ and $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, then $M/IM$ is a free module over $R/I$. A basis of $M$ is sent to a basis of $M/IM$ by the canonical projection.

Comment: OK. Which of these three fails to hold in a non-commutative ring, that a quotient with respect to a maximal ideal is a field, that $M/IM$ is free, or that the projection sends bases to bases? And how do you prove the last two hold for a commutative ring?

Comment: Try your hand at them. What you can say about $R/I$ when $I$ is a maximal twosided ideal is that it is simple, which surely doesn't imply IBN. What's true is that if a quotient of a ring has IBN, then the ring itself has IBN.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I prove that a commutative ring is stably finite?

For commutative rings, the ordinary determinant argument works.

From $\det(AB)=1$ you get that the determinant of $A$ is a unit, so you can form the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) and divide by the determinant with no problem to form the inverse of $A$. Thus any matrix ring over a commutative ring is Dedekind finite, hence the commutative ring is stably finite.

> could you give me an example of a stably finite non-commutative ring?

I guess you definitely want a ring that *isn't* commutative. How about the quaternions $\Bbb H$? Or any matrix ring over a field? Or any Noetherian ring of your choice?

Here's another example if those are too difficult to verify: try to show that finite rings are stably finite. Actually you can just show that finite rings are Dedekind finite, and then point out that matrix rings over finite rings are also finite, so they must be Dedekind finite by the same token. Thus a finite ring is stably finite.

Comment: OK. So. How does the determinant argument prove Dedekind finiteness for the matrix ring, i.e. the non-existence of a proper subset of that ring equinumerous to the whole of that ring? How does the Dedekind-finiteness of the matrix ring prove the stably finiteness of the ring? As for the examples, how do you prove those given examples are stably finite? And "any" Noetherian ring would include $\mathbb{Z}$ which is commutative. So you are saying any Noetherian ring is stably finite? Why?

Comment: Dear @MickG : "Dedekind finite ring" does not exactly mean "a ring that is Dedekind finite as a set" but it is the same flavor! A ring is Dedekind finite iff $ab=1$ implies $ba=1$ for all $a,b\in R$. When interpreted as $R$ module homomorphisms on $R$, this says that $R$ is isomorphic to a proper direct summand of itself.

Comment: @MickG Second question: "How does Dedekind finiteness of the matrix ring rove the stable finiteness of the ring?" This should also be obvious once you have the right defintion of Dedekind finite above :)

Comment: @MickG Third question: If we proved that a right Noetherian ring is stably finite, that would cover all cases. One approach is to show that a right Noetherian ring is Dedekind finite, and that a matrix ring over a right Noetherian ring is right Noetherian. Thus all matrix rings over a Noetherian ring are Noetherian, hence Dedekind finite, hence the ring is stably finite.

Comment: $\det(AB)=1$, so $\det A=\frac{1}{\det B}$, or $\det B=\frac{1}{\det A}$. Thus the inverse of $A$ is the adjugate divided by $\det A$, which must be $B$, since if $C$ is $\frac{1}{\det A}\mathrm{adj}(A)$, then $C\cdot I=C\cdot(A\cdot B)=(C\cdot A)\cdot B=I\cdot B=B$. But then $B=C$ and $BA=I$, implying the ring is stably finite. Of course, in general the argument doesn't hold as Binet's theorem, which is fundamental for the invertibility of $\det A$, fails to hold. This way no Dedekind finiteness is required.

Comment: OK I just saw the comments. For some reason they loaded only when I edited my last comment. That comment obviously renders answering the first questions merely a curiosity of mine, and I must say I'm not too interested in entering those proofs as "stably finite" and "Dedekind finite" are terms I have just seen for the first time and which I will probably see in the future. The third question, however, I do want to fill in the details of. So could you please? Btw my proof uses the Laplace formula for the determinant (implied in $C$ being two-sided inverse). It _does_ hold for comm. rings right?

Comment: "right Noetherian" means all right ideals are finitely generated, right?

Comment: @MickG "$R$ is stably finite = all $n\times n$ matrix rings over $R$ are Dedekind finite." Stable finiteness is just like strong Dedekind finiteness. Go ahead and look up "noetherian ring" in wikipedia.

Comment: Is this comment referring to "no Dedekind finiteness is required"? In that case, let me clarify: I meant "required for the proof", not "required for the result I am proving". The latter is of course true, as you noted: Dedekind finiteness of the matrix ring is required for stable finiteness of the ring.